# (Unity) How to get height value with content Size Fitter component?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm trying to get height value with content size fitter component on, but it always return 0.

```
void Start() {

    print(GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height);


}
```

it return 0, why is that?

please help, thanks

edit : here is the screenshots.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unity's UI system is kind of messy sometimes...
To read or modify that values you should use the [rectTransform.sizeDelta](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-sizeDelta.html) which is a Vector2.

You can read a lot of examples in this [Unity Thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/modify-the-width-and-height-of-recttransform.270993/?_ga=2.44962148.1558147400.1589685071-730228744.1504047368).

But a quick example, try instead of the `rect.height`:

```
void Start()
{
     print(GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y);
}
```

I hope it helps. Always try to search for that specific questions on google, it will probably show up some answer.